# Separate visual studio solution for unit testing?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing

I have a visual studio solution that contains around 18 projects. I want to write unit tests for those projects (by creating a test-project that contains unit tests against each source project).

Should I use a separate solution that contains all the test-projects? Or should I use Partitioned solution approach of Visual Studio 2008 and create a sub-solution for all test-projects?

Answer (score 5):

To put unit tests in a separate solution would seem to me to create problems. Inherently, unit tests must be able to reference the types (classes) they are testing. If in a separate solution then it implies a binary association. That would seem very 'difficult'.

So, to investigate the reasons for the question, and hopefully provide some help, these are the reasons I would put my unit tests in the same solution:

- Project referencing. I like to name unit tests projects as .Tests where  is the name of the production assembly holding the types being tested. That way they appear next to each other (alphabetical order) in VS.
- With TDD development I need rapid switching between production code and unit tests. It is about writing the code, not so much about post code testing.
- I can select the solution node at the top of the solution pane and say 'run all tests' (I use Resharper(.
- The build farm (TeamCity) always runs all tests on all commits. Much easier with them all in one solution.

As I write this I wonder why put them in another solution. Unit test have no meaning outside of the solution with the production code.

Perhaps you can explain why your asking the question. Can you see a problem with them being in the same solution. 18 projects does not, to me, seem like a lot. The solutions I work on have many more ... but if using Resharper (and why wouldn't you?) you will need sufficient RAM in you box.

Hope this is of some help.

Comment: Actually, the size of projects in my solution is very big and visual studio takes a lot of time to load the complete solution. Updating intelli-sense is another problem that takes sufficient time. Also, I need to separate the code from unit tests so that when a developer needs to write unit tests, he/she only works on the solution containing unit tests.

Comment: So I can help you need to quantify 'very big'. Multiple answers here dependent on what is 'very big'.